# How can I apply css properties to tab when click?

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<div class="abcd">
    <article class="xyz">
        <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        <hgroup><h1>Make it Personal</h1></hgroup>
    </article>
</div>
```

I have above 6 "article" tags inside div. I am using them as tabs. I have 6 pages and I have applied same code on all 6 pages. I want them to be highlighted when active. On click they will go to one of the 6 pages where same above code is available. I want to apply some css properties when tab to be active.

How can I implement this using simple javascript?

Comment: did you try to search it first?

Comment: I am getting code with jquery ...but  I want to use javascript

Comment: Do you want to apply css styles on `article` by onclicking on them ?

Comment: post your code which you have used.

Comment: please try thisit may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239609/how-to-dynamically-change-the-color-of-the-selected-menu-item-of-a-web-page)

Comment: yes inside article ...I want that article to be highlighted!

Comment: If you have a working jQuery script (because you said) then you can post it here to convert it to plain javascript.

Comment: post your code which you have used to function the tabs functionality, it would help us to nswer your question.

Comment: I dont have jquery code ...I have simply used

.abcd .xyz:active, .abcd .xyz:hover {
background-color: white;
border-color: #CFCFCE;
}
It is working on hover but not on active

Answer (score -1):

**This is some code that may help you.**

```
 html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:#222;
        background:#FFF;
    }
    body {
        padding:10px;
        font:76%/150%  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: 0; /* removes dotted border around a:active from Firefox */
    }
    #nav {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#708090 url(nav_bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #191970;
        border-width:1px 1px 1px 0;
    }
    #nav li {
        display:inline;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    #nav a:link,
    #nav a:visited {
        color:#000;
        background:#708090;
        padding:20px 40px 4px 10px;
        float:left;
        width:auto;
        border-right:1px solid #191970;
        text-decoration:none;
        font:bold 1em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
    }
    #nav a:hover {
        color:#fff;
        background:#191970;
    }
    #nav li:first-child a {
        border-left:1px solid #191970;
    }
    #home #nav-home a,
    #about #nav-about a,
    #contact #nav-contact a {
        background:#00FFFF; /* Active Page Color */
        color:#000;
        text-shadow:none;
    }
    #home #nav-home a:hover,
    #about #nav-about a:hover,
    #contact #nav-contact a:hover {
        background:#FFF;
        color:#000;
    }
    #nav a:active {
        background:#7FFF00; /*turns this color briefly when link is selected*/
        color:#000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body id="about">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="nav-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Rhv/1/)