# Set selected menu item in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have 3 links. When user click on 1st link (`EQUIP1`), I need to show it as the visited. Then remaining two links show as not visited. Then when user select 2nd link (`EQUIP2`) the remaining two links should show as not visited. I'm ok if changing the color of font to sign that this is the current enabled link.

```
<tr align="center"> 
  <td class="mainTBSectionTab">                                                
     <a href="...">EQUIP1</a>
   </td>
   <td class="mainTBSectionTab">                                                                                    
     <a href="...">EQUIP2</a>
   </td>     
   <td class="mainTBSectionTab">                                             
     <a href="...">EQUIP3</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You mean you want to trick the user into thinking the links point to pages they haven't visited yet, even though they have? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change the color of the selected menu item of a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239609/how-to-dynamically-change-the-color-of-the-selected-menu-item-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave and assuming you are using static pages you could give each page's active link a `.selected` class.

based on what you want you could have default styling like this

```
.mainTBSectionTab
    color: #000
    text-decoration: none

.mainTBSectionTab.selected
    text-decoration: underline
```

Then your HTML file for equip1.html would look like this

```
<tr align="center"> 
    <td class="mainTBSectionTab selected">                                                
         <a href="...">EQUIP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="mainTBSectionTab">                                                                                    
         <a href="...">EQUIP2</a>
    </td>     
    <td class="mainTBSectionTab">                                             
         <a href="...">EQUIP3</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On the other pages you would apply the `.selected` class on the corresponding links to simulate the effect of a selected link